# Why cycle behaves differently in just one iteration?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
gs = open("graph.txt", "r")

gp = gs.readline()
gp_splitIndex = gp.find(" ")
gp_nodeCount = int(gp[0:gp_splitIndex])
gp_edgeCount = int(gp[gp_splitIndex+1:-1])

matrix = [] # predecare the array
for i in range(0, gp_nodeCount):
    matrix.append([])
    for y in range(0, gp_nodeCount):
        matrix[i].append(0)

for i in range(0, gp_edgeCount-1):
    gp = gs.readline()
    gp_splitIndex = gp.find(" ") # get the index of space, dividing the 2 numbers on a row
    gp_from = int(gp[0:gp_splitIndex])
    gp_to = int(gp[gp_splitIndex+1:-1])
    matrix[gp_from][gp_to] = 1

print matrix
```

The file graph.txt contains this:

```
5 10
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 0
0 3
3 1
1 4
4 2
2 0
```

The first two number are telling me, that GRAPH has 5 nodes and 10 edges. The Following number pairs demonstrate the edges between nodes. For example "1 4" means an edge between node 1 and 4.

Problem is, the output should be this:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

But instead of that, I get this:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Only one number is different and I can't understand why is this happening. The edge "3 1" is not present. Can someone explain, where is the problem?

Comment: Why do you use find...could you just use split and parse as int()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matthias has it; you don't need `edgeCount - 1` since the `range` function doesn't include the end value in the iteration.

There are several other things you can do to clean up your code:

- The `with` operator is preferred for opening files, since it closes them automatically for you
- You don't need to call `find` and manually slice, `split` already does what you want.
- You can convert and assign directly to a pair of numbers using a generator expression and iterable unpacking
- You can call `range` with just an end value, the `0` start is implicit.
- The multiplication operator is handy for initializing lists

With all of those changes:

```
with open('graph.txt', 'r') as graph:
    node_count, edge_count = (int(n) for n in graph.readline().split())
    matrix = [[0]*node_count for _ in range(node_count)]
    for i in range(edge_count):
        src, dst = (int(n) for n in graph.readline().split())
        matrix[src][dst] = 1

print matrix
# [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: But when I delete the -1 from range(), i get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Őkola\IVT\Python\Graph01_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    gp_to = int(gp[gp_splitIndex+1:-1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Just use `split` instead of `find` and slicing like I show in my example code. Otherwise, omit the `-1` from the end -- just use `[gp_splitIndex+1:]` -- putting a `-1` there means you're skipping the last character.

Answer (score 5):

Change `for i in range(0, gp_edgeCount-1):` to

```
for i in range(0, gp_edgeCount):
```

The `range()` function already does the "-1" operation. `range(0,3) "==" [0,1,2]`

And it is not the "3 1" edge that is missing, it is the "2 0" edge that is missing, and that is the last edge. The matrices start counting at 0.

Answer (score 2):

Just to keep your code and style, of course it could be much more readable:

```
gs = open("graph.txt", "r")
gp = gs.readline()

gp_splitIndex = gp.split(" ")
gp_nodeCount = int(gp_splitIndex[0])
gp_edgeCount = int(gp_splitIndex[1])
matrix = [] # predecare the array
for i in range(0, gp_nodeCount):
    matrix.append([])
    for y in range(0, gp_nodeCount):
        matrix[i].append(0)


for i in range(0, gp_edgeCount):
    gp = gs.readline()
    gp_Index = gp.split(" ") # get the index of space, dividing the 2 numbers on a row
    gp_from = int(gp_Index[0])
    gp_to = int(gp_Index[1])
    matrix[gp_from][gp_to] = 1

print matrix
```

Exactly is the last instance not used..the 2 0 from your file. Thus the missed 1. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, another version similar to the one of tzaman:

```
with open('graph.txt', mode='r') as txt_file:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in txt_file.readlines()]

number_pairs = [[int(n) for n in line.split(' ')] for line in lines]

header = number_pairs[0]
edge_pairs = number_pairs[1:]

num_nodes, num_edges = header
edges = [[0] * num_nodes for _ in xrange(num_nodes)]
for edge_start, edge_end in edge_pairs:
    edges[edge_start][edge_end] = 1

print edges
```